# CSS Custom div height

Tags: html, css

I have simple layout and I'm trying to expand div's height to given % so I can put later scalled background img using backgound-size.

In example I wanna have div1 expand to 69%.

Why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/mc6ecstr/

### CSS:

```
body
{
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 1080px;
}
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 15.67%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    height: 69%; /*doesnt work*/

}
#div2 {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    width: 43.17%;
    margin-right: 3.6%;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="div1">1</div>
        <div id="div2">2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give to the `body` and `html` and to his `parent (#container)` height: 100%;

**CSS**

```
body, html
{
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%; /* Add this */
}

#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* Add this */
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/mc6ecstr/1/)**

Comment: Nice work, Luis. And if OP meant 69% of Body's height (as opposed to screen height), OP can set body's height to 1080px (as in code above) but adding Luis' tip to set html height of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of `#header` you can use `calc(...)` and absolute positioning to make the container fill the remaining space:

```
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    height:calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

In this example I've set the header to a fixed height of 20px, then offset container by the same amount.

Then set `#div1`'s height accordingly to fill 69% of #container.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/mc6ecstr/2/