# Full height div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I would like to know if there is a way to create a full height div with css.

I've tried absolute positioning, but that is not as flexible as I would like to have it, but it is my current method.

Flex boxes are not a option because of compatibility reasons.

```
.line{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 0%, blue 100%);
    width: 1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px; /*Fixed height at the moment*/
}
```

**[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nxgw3kdo/1/)**

---

Here is the current method I'm using: absolute positioning.

Not every box width is fitting for bootstrap. (I actually have one for every col in bootstrap)

```
.line{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 0%, blue 100%);
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 33.33333%;
}
```

**[Current Method JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxgw3kdo/18/)**

Comment: `height: 100%;` will make it the height of its parent. If the parent is the body then add `html, body { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: @Ruddy That would require `height: 100%` on every parents parent, or a fixed height. Flexible height containers are not possible this way.

Comment: You have not given us all the information we need then? Your questions isn't that clear. Are you trying to create an overlay or something? Please create a working demo of the problem.

Comment: The `.line` has to be the full height of the container, instead of a fixed height. That is basically everything. I'll edit my post with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` (current viewport)

**CSS**

```
.line{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 0%, blue 100%);
    width: 1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    float: left;
    height: 80vh; /*Full screen Height*/
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nxgw3kdo/14/)**

Comment: this will only work if the site is no larger than the current viewport. What if the site is twice the height? with a 3000px high body http://jsfiddle.net/nxgw3kdo/11/

Comment: I already answer that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035083/css-custom-div-height/30035159?noredirect=1#comment48187269_30035159

Comment: @LuisP.A. "vh" is also impractical, because it is basically just a fixed height depending on the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your problem but try the following code ?

```
   .content{
     background-color: red; // color was for the test
     height: 100%;
     padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: height 100% will only work if the `.content` is absolute positioned.

Comment: You're just changing the background-color to red... Edit: I know this is for testing, but the following code is already in my first fiddle x)

Comment: Sorry, it was only display the content (test).

Answer (score 0):

```
body { margin:0; /* This is used to reset any browser-default margins */ }

div {
    height:100vh;
    background:#f00;
    color:#fff;
}
```

This is applied to div hope this helps..

Comment: this does not work at all. Also "vh" is basically just a fixed height depending on the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

> The .line has to be the full height of the container, instead of a fixed height. That is basically everything. I'll edit my post with a working example. –  AlexG May 5 at 9:26

Your current absolute positioning method already does this. `.line` is 100% of `.row`'s height. I think you are asking for the height of `.line` to take the full height of `.panel-body`. If that is a correct assumption, you just need to move `position:relative;` from `.row` to `.panel-body` (See Snippet).

**Snippet**

```css
.panel-body {
  position:relative;
  }

.line1{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 0%, blue 100%);
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 33.33333%;
}
.line2{
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 0%, blue 100%);
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 66.66666%;
}
.content{
    background-color: #EDFBFF;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.container{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Full height div</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="content" style="height: 150px;">line should fill 100% of the height automatically</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="content"  style="height: 200px;">absolute positioning is unpractical, but my current solution with "left: 50%;" for example. </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="content" style="height: 300px;">flex is also not an option for compatibility reasons</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```